# lineTo not woking

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Ok I have this piece of code which is supposed to be drawing a simple house but when i run it I get nothing and no warnings that something is wrong with it. anyone know why?

```
function onLoad() 
{ 
    var canvas; 
    var context;
function initialise () 
{
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
    if (!canvas) 
    { 
        alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!'); 
        return; 
    }
    if (!canvas.getContext) 
    { 
        alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!'); 
        return; 
    }
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    if (!context) 
    { 
        alert('Error: failed to getContext!'); 
        return; 
    } 
}

function draw()
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(150,100);
    context.lineTo(250,200);
    context.lineTo(250,300);
    context.lineTo(50,300);
    context.lineTo(50,200);
    context.lineTo(150,100);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
}

initialise();
draw(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code, including HTML?

Comment: where is your onLoad() function called ?

Comment: There seem to be nothing wrong with it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFH3X/1/)

Answer (score 0):

the code should work fine, but I think you forget to call your onLoad() function, so nothing can happen

change onLoad() with

```
window.onload = function () {
... //your code
}
```

(and it will not draw a house, just the roof ;-) )

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, also that is code for a full house not just a roof

Comment: have you seen this? http://jsfiddle.net/rFH3X/1/ (from the comments above by @Christofer Eliasson)

Comment: yes I have seen that but if you look that is only showing 2 lines whilst my code specifies 5 lines meaning that something is wrong somewhere